# construction of a function such that it fails to be analytic at zero of function

Tags: complex-analysis

is there any function whose  zero is singular point of  function ?
i.e. construct a complex valued function such that there is zero of function at which it fails to be analytic
f: D to C is a function where D is subset of C

Comment: So you want a function $\;f\;$ s.t. $\;f(z_0)=0\;$ but $\;f\;$ isn't analytic at $\;z_0\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

What about

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}\frac1z\;,\;\;z\neq 0\\{}\\0\;,\;\;z=0\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;?$$